# how to implement chart control in Windows 10 UWP

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I need to implement linear graph. Is there any chart control for Windows 10 UWP?  Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I looked into this about 6 months ago, and at that time there was no first party chart control. This could have changed. The normal solution is to make a custom control. You may be able to find such third party chart controls online, otherwise you would have to make your own.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Syncfusion provides free license to independent developers for their Essential Studio suite. They have some great visualization tools. You can check them here:
https://www.syncfusion.com/products/uwp

You can find more information about its free license at following link:
https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Comment: Syncfusion advertise UWP controls yet I fail to see them after installing their library. I'm pretty sure by UWP they instead mean Universal Windows Phone Apps (8.1)? Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Syncfusion has controls for Universal Windows Platform (UWP), but you need to install on Windows 10.

Comment: LinkedIn is required for signing up for a free community license.

Answer (score 6):

Filip Skakun has made a great library that has several charting options available!
It has been possible to use it in WinRT and he is in the works on porting it to UWP ( Win 10 ).

The links you can follow to get more info

https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit ( the complete lib )
https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/tree/master/WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization/WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Shared/Charting ( charting part )

Best contact Filip on twitter to see how far the porting is done... https://mobile.twitter.com/xyzzer

Answer (score 1):

I was recently researching this very question and discovered [LiveCharts](https://lvcharts.net/)

Answer (score 1):

[Telerik UI for UWP](https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP) is also an option.

which is also packed if you install [Windows Template Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WASTeamAccount.WindowsTemplateStudio)

**Nuget package:** `Telerik.UI.for.UniversalWindowsPlatform`