# Charts in UWP Windows 10 App

Tags: charts, windows-10, uwp

I want to add a line char to my UWP App for Windows 10. I cannot not find control in the toolbox to add charts to my application. How can I a chart to my app?

Comment: On NuGet, search for and install this package: `WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to implement chart control in Windows 10 UWP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338217/how-to-implement-chart-control-in-windows-10-uwp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not too much to choose from yet but the **WinRTXamlToolkit** has UWP specific builds and these could be a good starting point.

They don't resemble the polished commercial alternatives but it might be helpful.

These are the NuGet packages I used for chart and gauges.

```
WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.UWP
WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Gauge.UWP
```

This is the underlying repo: https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit

Answer (score 0):

There are no native controls for creating charts in UWP. You can either choose a paid solution or a free one. There are a lot of options out there. Check this answer too. 
[how to implement chart control in Windows 10 UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338217/how-to-implement-chart-control-in-windows-10-uwp)